# getting Internal Server error with dynamic fieldset and standard controller

Tags: visualforce, fieldsets, dynamic-binding

I have the following inline visualforce page which gives me an internal server error.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Agreement__c">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Agreement__c.FieldSets.MyFieldset}” var="f"> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!Agreement__c[f.fieldPath]}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

This fieldset is pulling fields from related objects and if I switch to one that is only pulling fields from the object itself it works correctly.

Is this a known limitation around fieldsets and dynamic binding?

**NEW:** After some additional testing this appears to only occur when I pull in related fields from the agreement object itself. e.g. I have a lookup to agreement__c on agreement__c and the page only throws internal server error when using that lookup but pulling in from other related objects works fine.

Error ID: 1936706758-1056 (1347345803)

Comment: `var="f"` in line 2 and `[f.fieldPath]` on line 3 have the same value, which is the API name for the field on this object. It sounds like your request is specifically about rendering fields defined in the fieldset that are acquired from related records. Correct? (`f` is a `Schema.FieldSetMember` and in this case it's .toString() method returns the field name)

Comment: @MarkPond, yes, I got the same results with both. I did some more testing and it appears to only occur when using a lookup to the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code and recreated it using the `Account` object along with a new fieldset called `MyFieldset`. It worked rendering fields on the `Account`record as well as the `User` record via lookup reference.

Your code looks to work perfectly as written.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.MyFieldset}" var="f"> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!Account[f.fieldPath]}" />
    </apex:repeat> 

</apex:page>
```

Which rendered `YesGenePointMark Pond`; the three fields in my set were `Active`, `Name` and `Owner > Name`.

You'll have to elaborate on your question to get much more assistance.

Comment: Can you try adding some fields from the parent account to the fieldset. I was able to reproduce this error on accounts like that.

Comment: @GregGrinberg yup, this is a problem that shows up when using a self-reference to the same object type in a VF context. Just rendering `<apex:outputText value="{!f}" />` does show the correct path to the field but trying to bind to that field on the object fails with the internal server error. I'd open a case about it and include the gack id that you appended to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I got a similar crash. I was on API 24, changed to 41 and it worked

Comment: this would be better suited as a comment rather than an answer unles you provide a solid explanation on why this should work.

Comment: This answer seems legitimate. As versions change, bugs get fixed. It seems like this particular question was one such case. Voting not to delete.